# An algorithm to place circles in a field so that they overlap completely, the range of the radius of the circle is given

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEO2o.png)You are given a field(regular or irregular) and you need to place circles in such a way that they:

1. Overlap completely.
2. No place on the field is left out.
3. Circle's area shouldn't go out of the field.
4. Most efficient number of circles are used

Eg, you're given a random field with dimensions(20-30metres) and also the circle's radius range(4-10)metres.
How to obtain the most effective solution?

Comment: What do 1) and 3) mean? Could you try to formalize these requirements?

Comment: @NicoSchertler the side of one circle touches the centre of the other circle.

Comment: and for 3) the circles shouldn't go out of the field,all circles must be inside the field

Comment: Then I guess most field shapes would require an infinite number of circles (unless your field boundary are piecewise circular arcs).

Comment: can you please elaborate more ?@NicoSchertler

Comment: What you're asking is impossible; you cannot cover the area close to a corner of a rectangle if the circles have a size limit and can't go over the edge of the rectangle.

Comment: I don't know what "Most efficient number of circles are used" means. Do you mean that you want to use as few circles as possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information about how to ask a good question.

Comment: @m69 I need to create the most efficient algorithm(minimal error), it's fine to leave out those corner spaces.

Comment: @JimMischel yes but that's least priority, what I'm trying to say is that circle's shouldn't be wasted to the max extent.

Comment: @JimMischel Can I please message you separately because it's an idea and it's hard to explain without stating the idea point blank publicly. Thank you

Comment: This is the second time you've asked this question, and it's as vague as the first one. If you're not giving us all the necessary information, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: @m69 please look at the link provided, I'm trying to create an algorithm that can effectively place sprinklers on a field. Please tell me if you don't understand my question, I require your help and I'm grateful you replied